# Catholic - What are the best arguments for Mark 16:9-20 being Inspired scripture?

Tags: catholicism, gospel-of-mark, manuscript

As a Catholic, I have to take it as a dogmatic tenet of faith that everything in the Latin Vulgate during the council of Trent was inspired by the Holy Sprit.

That being said, I am seeing good arguments for Mark 16:9-20 being later additions, for example, it is missing from both Vaticanus and Sinaiticus.

What would be the best arguments in favor of Mark 16:9-20 being part of the original text?

Edit:
I found this (very long) article very helpful in answering this question for myself. I realize now looking back that this question deserves a small book as an answer and is therefore not appropriate for this medium. If you are also asking this question I recommend you read the article linked to below. God bless!

https://www.bereanpatriot.com/majority-text-vs-critical-text-vs-textus-receptus-textual-criticism-101/

Comment: You ask two different questions. Is Mark 16:9-20 inspired and is it part of the original text. Not part of the original text does not mean it was not inspired. Other books have endings which were written by a different writer. That does not mean both the main part and the ending were not both inspired.

Comment: @RevelationLad Isn't it accepted that only the original autographs are inspired?

Comment: Upon later reflection I realized this is a silly problem to get hung up on. Many books in the Bible do not have one author. For example, the book of Daniel could have easily been written by anywhere from two to more different people at different times. If multiple authors prior to initial promulgation is a deal breaker then Christianity falls apart before Christ was ever born and half your Bible no matter you denomination would be trash.

Comment: @MikeBorden Yes. However the organization of the inspired works is a human decision. If Mark was written first there are good reasons why it was inspired to end at verse 8 and good reasons why it was inspired to be completed later. The final placement which arranges them in a logical position relative to one another is no different than the endings of other books like Deuteronomy or Joshua.

Comment: As a Catholic I'd have to say that any arguments that question dogmatically defined truths can't be good by definition. Modern(ist) biblical "scholars" question everything from the authorship to the historicity of Scripture through a naturalist lens. For example, the now common dating of the Gospels is based upon the "fact" that it is impossible for Christ to predict the destruction of the temple. I'd disregard anything that goes against the thousand-year tradition of the Church. Unlike Protestants we don't have to verify each part of our faith. By being Catholic we get the whole Truth.

Comment: This is a matter of the science of Textual Criticism and, in particular, the place of Vaticanus and Sinaiticus in regard to all the other evidence available. Dean John Burgon argues against putting undue weight on those two in his book _Revision Revised_ and Herman Hoskier strongly advises against accepting the recension in the 5th century (and the part played in that recension by those two documents) in his book _Codex B and its Allies_. This question might better be answered on SE-Biblical Hermeneutics.

Comment: @M__ It's my understanding that we do not have the original of Mark.

Comment: @MikeBorden I never said we did, but "originals" should be "original" (singular), apologies for the typo

Comment: @M__ [Code Sinaiticus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codex_Sinaiticus) was discovered in a monastery near Mount Sinai by Tischendorf in 1844. Textual Criticism (of the Greek text) is irrespective of who studies it. My being a Protestant is irrelevant to the discussion and I point out that you are discriminating against me by your remark.

Comment: @NigelJ Codex Sinaiticus and Codex Sinaiticus Syriacus (discovered by the Smith sisters) are two different manuscripts with the same passage missing. Codex Sinaiticus (1844) written in Greek and Codex Sinaiticus Syriacus (1892) in Syriac. Dating is complicated but Codex Sinaiticus appears earlier by possibly 340 years. When the 2 oldest codices have 16:9-20 missing - maybe its the sample, but when 3 ancient codices emerge it looks convincing.

Comment: @NigelJ discriminating I do apologise if you feel that. Dean John Burgon was probably a high Anglican (I could be wrong though) and within the broad Anglican church this could be a sensitive issue. I have not read your books and no offence was meant. I'm not ordained, or anything similar, so I might overstep the mark without realising.

Comment: @M_ Thank you. I encourage you to read Herman Hoskier _Codex B and its Allies_ wherein he points out a recension which occurred in the 5th century (of which Sinaiticus and Vaticanus are examples). This was a Coptic recension and he advises (and I fully support this) that the recension was in error and was later corrected. The correction is the _Textus Receptus_. The _uncorrected_ recension is the Critical Text of 1881 which leans _very heavily_ on Sinaiticus and Vaticanus. Which disagree with one another in over 3,000 places _in just the gospels_. Source : Dean Burgon _Revision Revised_.

Comment: The Vulgate is an authoritative Latin translation, not inspired. Only the original manuscripts are inspired. Translators and copiests carry forward inspiration only insofar as they are accurate to the original text. Trent is saying that you can trust the Latin Vulgate to accurately express the original texts and meaning of Holy Sciprutre, insofar as it can be expressed, in the Latin language.

Comment: Very helpful clarification, thank you! @jaredad7

Answer (score 2):

This is as big (bigger) problem for Protestants than it is for Roman Catholics - for very different theological reasons. In the Protestant church it can simply be omitted, but it isn't. It's the same basic practical issue, questioning this passage upsets Christians. In Protestant churches it complicates the common understanding of the inerrancy.

It's useful to clear the background to the question. My understanding of the council of Trent (I'm not RC).

- It was a very significant event in response to the Reformation.
- The interpretation subject to huge debate much later, Vatican I sort of thing.
- *It declared the Latin Vulgate as adequate for doctrinal proofs rather than the original Hebrew and Greek manuscripts*

Thus, Mark 16:9-20 is therefore part of the Latin Vulgate, as it is in Protestant bibles. Whatever the Vulgate was at the Council of Trent, thats the Roman Catholic bible, because the issues post-council of Trent concern Tradition *et* Scripture, not what is the relevance of Mark 16:9-20.

The timing of the Council is relevant as to whether  the issue was widely known. Moreover, how much authority at the time would have been placed on a single book? The real underlying issue surfaced when  supporting codices were discovered much later notably in 1844 and then 1892.

---

I would politely suggest there is very little evidence for Mark 16:9-20 being part of the original Gospel of Mark. The arguments are well known:

- the discovery of the codex Sinaiticus (1844) and the Codex Sinaiticus Syriacus (1892) confirmed codex Vaticanus. Thus, all the earliest codices are in agreement.
- I believe the Codex Sinaiticus Syriacus contains the words "The End" after Mark 16:8, which seems pretty strong evidence.
- Obviously the style of writing is completely different to the Gospel of Mark.
- There are difficulties with the contents of the passage:

1. Drinking deadly poisons and snake bites: I would suggest of all the Christian blessings immunity from poisons and snake bites does not appear high on the list of priorities. The Council of Trent concerned salvation, rather than clinical toxicity. Moreover, I would advise any individual suffering toxicity to seek immediate medical attention rather than proclaim Scriptural authority over a disputed passage.
2. Jesus rebukes his disciples. This is not the Jesus of the bible. The biblical Jesus has incredible patience, and never *collectively* (stress intentional) rebukes his disciples. It also seems to contradict Jesus' restoration of the leadership of Peter at the end of the Gospel of John. If you were going to rebuke someone, Peter's denial of Jesus seems pretty good grounds for doing so.

There are additional arguments of context.

- The Gospel of Mark starts with a bang, a vagrant in the middle of a desert dressed in camel hair, very little historical context;
- it ends with a bang at Mark 16:8.
- The repetition of predicting the resurrection is in the build up to this dramatic conclusion.
- Arguments such as "the original ending went missing" purported on grammatical criteria have not stood up to subsequent analysis on bigger sample sizes of ancient Greek correspondence.

Thus what I am leading up to is simply that @RevelationLad's response is the most consistent answer from a Roman Catholic perspective. Here the authority of the Council of Trent is clear. Ultimately, I would (obviously) argue its about individual belief.

**My thoughts**
By tradition the Gospel of Mark was written under the authority of Peter. I think the ending is very much in character of Peter. He never really appeared to consider the long term ramifications of short term decisions. If you want to get people into your church, ending on a cliff-hanger is exactly how to do it. Thus, I think it points to the Gospel of Mark being written and distributed when the witnesses to the resurrection were still alive. These are just thoughts however not an argument for the Gospel of Mark ending on 16:8 and the discussion of dating when the Gospel of Mark was written is a separate question.